# how to run android emulator with TTS enabled

Tags: android-emulator

i hope i am not posting a duplicate question, can anyone please tell me how to enable TTS in android emulator enabled when eclipse starts it when we run the project.

is it that i have to start with SD card or sth like that?? Also for some reason when i go to my Run Configuration in eclipse i don't see any field to pass arguments for emulator.

thanks

Comment: ok not sure how, i restarted my eclipse wiping out all the user data and it works, voila!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it with the help of one blog.
First we should have SDcard.
Second download tts*.apk
open the cmd(in windows environment)
type adb instll tts*.apk (this will install tts to android emulator)

following this steps will be OK 
good luck